# I am trying to wake the android phone, using PowerManager. However, SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK seems to be deprecated

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am trying to wake the android phone, using PowerManager. However, SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK seems to be deprecated. Does anyone know how to approach this another way?

```
public class ShakeToWake extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "YourServie");
                mWakeLock.acquire();

                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

                mWakeLock.release();
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that there was a legitimate reason for the deprecation.  Security reasons, perhaps?  Or phones lighting up for no apparent reason.

Comment: They're doing it in a different way now, that's all.  It says what the replacement is in the api docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs by google tell you the replacement for it- Most applications should use FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON instead of this type of wake lock, as it will be correctly managed by the platform as the user moves between applications and doesn't require a special permission.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON